# Error while posting data to asmx web service using ajax and writing response in html page using a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web-services

I have created a asmx web service as follows:

```
    [ScriptService]
public class CurrencyData : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string DisplayCurrency(double currency, string symbol ,string format)
    {
        switch(format)
        {
            case "short": symbol = "EUR";
                break;
            case "long": symbol = "EURO";
                break;
            case "simple":
                break;
        }
        return currency.ToString() + symbol;
    }


}
```

On the client side I have created an external js script to call above service containing the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function displaycurrency(monval, sym, fmt) {    
var output;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:60413/CurrencyData.asmx/DisplayCurrency",  
    data: "currency=" + monval + "&symbol=" + sym + "&format=" + fmt + "",           //posting the required currency & symbol        
    dataType: "text",      
    success: function (data) {
        var xmlout = $.parseXML(data);            
        output = xmlout.childNodes[0].innerHTML; //getting the currency value from xml
    }
});
return output;
});
```

I am using the the defined function to be called in an html page to display the currency value in between script tags:

```
<p id="#price" ><script>displaycurrency("22.56", "$", "long")</script></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/CurrencyHLPR.js">/script>
//external js
```

But when I am trying to run the code it is giving "displaycurrency is not defined" error. I intend to used this method in multiple places in the html to print different currency formats. I am not very familiar in consuming web services through scripts/ajax, so not sure of other approach. Please give a solution.

Comment: Are you in a ASP.NET environment?

Comment: @IndieRok Well kind of, but I am restricted to using plain html than aspx or cshtml.

Comment: Ok I see, let me check what I can do to help.

Comment: Ok, I made it working, will post the answer

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard for me to fully understand the outcome you want and the process, lacking background information on the project and all. Nevertheless, here's how I made it work. My example is really basic, but I suppose you'll be able to adapt it to your need.

I my JS file, I first obtain the value of the P tag, which I changed the configuration a bit (Instead of calling the function inside the P tag). I split the string into an array to obtain each parameters. I then call a function which in turn calls the ajax function. Once the result is returned from the webservice, I display the outcome in a new P tag, to show that the call was successful.

I changed your WebService code a bit, I stripped out your CurrencyData Class. Not knowing your full intent, you'll have to tell me if this class is mandatory or not and I'll rectify the situation.

Here is the WebService.cs. Note that the 'using System.Web.Script.Services;' is mandatory if you want to use your DisplayCurrency method with an AJAX call:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
 //[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public WebService () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    [ScriptMethod]
    [WebMethod]
    public string DisplayCurrency(double currency, string symbol, string format)
    {
        switch (format)
        {
            case "short": symbol = "EUR";
                break;
            case "long": symbol = "EURO";
                break;
            case "simple":
                break;
        }
        return currency.ToString() + " " + symbol;
    }    
}
```

On the client side, I added the ajax code in a JS file, main.js:

```
//Document ready
$(document).ready(function () {
    var results;
    //Get P tag text
    var testStr = $('#price').text();
    //Split string into an array with a character delimiter
    var arrayT = testStr.split(',');
    //Call displaycurrency function. Each array index represents a function parameter
    displaycurrency(arrayT[0], arrayT[1], arrayT[2]);
});

//displaycurrency function
var output;
function displaycurrency(monval, sym, fmt) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/WebService.asmx/DisplayCurrency",
        data: "currency=" + monval + "&symbol=" + sym + "&format=" + fmt + "",           //posting the required currency & symbol        
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            var xmlout = $.parseXML(data);
            output = xmlout.childNodes[0].innerHTML; //getting the currency value from xml  
            //Display result in another P tag
            $(".result").text(output);        
        }
    });
}
```

The simple index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="price">22.56,$,long</p>
    <p class="result"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Much appreciate your response,but as I mentioned in above case I have multiple occurences of currency, so I'll then have to make that many ids. Hence I intend to use a js function to pass parameters in script tags so only the formatted output e.g "22.56EUR" or "22.56EUROS" will be returned in the p tags.